# UnityAction fails to capture closure variable in Coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine, closures, coroutine

Given the following hierarchy:

```
- Canvas
    - Toggle 1
    - Toggle 2
    - Toggle 3
```

where The toggles have a common ToggleGroup and only one Toggle is initially selected, and the following script attached to the Canvas:

```
public class Testscript : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine (LateStart ());
    }

    IEnumerator LateStart() {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
        var toggles = GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle> ();
        foreach (Toggle toggle in toggles) {
            var captured = toggle;
            captured.onValueChanged.AddListener (b => {
                Debug.Log (captured.name + " changed to " + b);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

no matter what toggle I select, the output is:

```
Toggle 3 changed to False
Toggle 3 changed to True
```

But if I put the creation of the `UnityAction<bool>` inside of a function like this:

```
public class Testscript : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine (LateStart ());
    }

    IEnumerator LateStart() {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
        var toggles = GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle> ();
        foreach (Toggle toggle in toggles) {
            var captured = toggle;
            captured.onValueChanged.AddListener (makeListener(captured));
        }
    }

    private UnityAction<bool> makeListener(Toggle toggle) {
        return b => {
            Debug.Log (toggle.name + " changed to " + b);
        };
    }
}
```

I get expected results like these:

```
Toggle 1 changed to False
Toggle 2 changed to True
```

What is going on here? Why doesn't this work in a Coroutine?

It's also noteworthy that the first example *does* work as expected if I export and run as an UWP App instead of a standalone Build, so I suspect this behavior is caused by an implementation detail I am not aware of.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I would suggest you first update Unity to the latest version([5.4.0F1](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta)) then try it again. If this problem is still there,go to **Help** -> **Report a Bug**. Wait for a reply from Unity.

Comment: Not a bug, just the way it works. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/974036/c-lambda-call-in-for-loop-references-to-last-objec.html

Comment: Looks like a broken implementation of coroutines to me, especially because it works when compiled and run in VS as an UWP app